# How to disable haptic feedback for (software) keyboard?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, keyboard, haptic-feedback

On my Samsung Galaxy SIII, when the screen is unlocked, by default when the user presses
any of the hardware keys Menu (the key on the left) or Back (the key on the right) the
phone virates slightly and then if the user keeps holding such buttons then the phone
emits another slight vibration corresponding to the long press, and the same happens
when the user long-presses the Home hardware key (the key in the middle).

Since I didn't like this bahavior I went to `Settings -> My device -> Power saving mode (turned it on) -> Turn off haptic feedback (made sure this checkbox was checked)`. This
disabled the slight vibration occurring when the above-mentioned hardware buttons are
pressed, but the phone still vibrates slightly when the buttons on the software keyboard
are pressed.

Is there a way to disable haptic feedback for the software keybaord as well?

Thanks.

Comment: You can also reduce haptic feedback (for GUI elements like menus, not for the virtual keyboard) or turn it off completely in `Settings / My device / Sound / Vibration Intensity / Haptic feedback`. There is a slider that can be set from off to various strengths to maximum. This is at least when having Android version 4.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

Go to `Settings > Language and Input`.  Click the settings icon on the Samsung keyboard, go to `Advanced` and uncheck `Vibration`.

Comment: Good, glad to have helped :)

Comment: I've also noticed the sound made when tapping the keyboard can also be turned off from this screen, which was also helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: You are a life saver.  I was about to throw this dumb phone right out the window.  Keyboard vibrate is so obnoxious, can't believe any sane person would have forced that on us as a default!